# Heroku - internal server error

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku-toolbelt

Trying to deploy my project with Heroku while following the step by step guide and I realize that I cannot run syncdb -> I am getting an error

```
bash: python.manage.py: command not found
```

same thing if I try to deploy and open my app with Heroku I am getting a 500 - internal server error.

Am I supposed to be using another type of database than the one provided with Django and the development server?

Comment: here is my github project https://github.com/henrigeek/Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your error, it says that the command you inputted was `python.manage.py`. The correct command is `python manage.py`(WITHOUT THE DOT BETWEEN PYTHON AND MANAGE.PY).

Now run `python manage.py` and see if it is running locally, if not then try fixing the errors that it throws when you run it locally because most of the time those are the errors that heroku is throwing as well.